# Parse json from the current page in browser developer tools console

Tags: javascript, json

When looking at the results of a url in my browser and I would like to open up the Developer Tools javascript console and use javascript commands to analyze the results of the page.  Here's an example page:

<strike>http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t&q=deep&page_limit=2&page=1</strike>

Note - I'm changing the url for this - rotten tomatoes' URL isn't public and my key expired.  This example from jsontest works with the accepted answer.

http://echo.jsontest.com/movies/ET

Is there a way to click on this, launch the firebug console (or something similar in another browser) and parse this json string so I could use common javascript to inspect the json object.

EDIT

JQuery is not available...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Chrome, I opened the link above and went to Chrome's Developer Tools (F12) and entered the following command in the console...

```
JSON.parse(document.body.textContent)
```

It returns a the object representation quite nicely.  From there is an easy matter to manipulate and play with the object in Javascript.  For instance...

```
JSON.parse(document.body.textContent).movies.length
```

...returns 2.

Comment: Works in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.  Thanks!

Comment: I get error messages when I try this in Firefox?